# Query related to Pointers and Arrays

Tags: c

The questions from my textbook is:

Write a function that returns a pointer to float and has two parameters: 1)a two dim array of floats with COL column and 2)an integer that represents the number of rows. Returned pointer should point to an array of floats containing the sum of the elements in the corresponding row of the 2 dim array.

My solution is:

```
float* ptr (float array[][COL], int rows) {
    float *ptr;
    int j; 

    for (j=0; j<COL; j++)
        *ptr += array[rows][j];

    return *ptr; 
}
```

I just wonder whether this solution is correct? Thank you very much.

Comment: No, and this code also won't compile.

Comment: Please fix your syntax errors, e.g. `arry` and `array`, also what type is COL?

Comment: @Nobilis Done, sorry. Also COL is an int

Comment: *"I just wonder whether this solution is correct?"* - Did **you** try to compile and run it? Did it produce the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

You've not allocated any memory for `ptr` to point at, so the answer is unavoidably wrong.  You have to ensure that the memory will last long enough to be usable, so you can't return a pointer to an automatic array; you'll either have to have a static array (but how do you make it big enough), or you'll have to dynamically allocate the memory (`malloc()` et al) and then make sure the calling code frees what was allocated.

You also have algorithmic problems.  You're accumulating all the values for all rows into a single value, whereas you're requested to calculate a separate value for each row.

Also, `*ptr` is a `float`; you'd need just `return ptr;` to have the types correct.

Your function name needs to be different, too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { COL = 7 };

float *row_sums(float array[][COL], int rows)
{
    float *ptr = malloc(rows * sizeof(*ptr));
    if (ptr != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
                ptr[i] += array[i][j];
    }
    return ptr;
}

int main(void)
{
    float data[][COL] = { { 1.0 }, { 2.0 }, { 0.0, 3.0 }, { -1.0, -2.0 } };
    float *result = row_sums(data, 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%d: %.1f\n", i, result[i]);
    free(result);
    return(0);
}
```

The use of `4` is sub-optimal; it should be something like `ROWS`, where that's defined using:

```
enum { ROWS = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]) } ;
```